# xamarin ios project properties

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am having a strange issue with a xamarin IOS project. On one machine when you go to the ios project -> properties. It shows the options like this:

**IOS Project Properties Wrong**
[image: IOS Project Properties Wrong]

In the other machine's project the properties look like this:

**IOS Project Properties Correct:**
[image: IOS Project Properties Correct]

You will notice that the IOS Application tab is visible in this project and the iOS Build section has a General and Advanced tab. Why doesn't the other project have this. On both machines I just created a Cross platform PCL template project. Both machines have the latest xamarin installs. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. The issue here is that with visual studio 4.5 they changed the way that the projects worked. For me personally I cannot deploy xamarin ios. Because of the ITMS-90096 error. Even when I set the images in the info.plist file I still get errors. I will instead revert back to release 4.4 until I can properly deploy to the app store.

[Xamarin Release Notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.5/)